# CompareAttribute ValidationResult has an empty MemberNames

Tags: .net-4.5, data-annotations

**Code:**

```
public class RegistrationViewModel {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public String ComfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The `ValidationResult` produced by `CompareAttribute` has an empty `MemberNames`. I would expect `MemberNames` to include at least "ConfirmPassword".

Right now I'm taking special action for `ValidationResults` that can't be linked back to a property but it would be better in this case if it could be linked back.

Do I have to write a custom CompareAttribute?